# Use mbind to move pages in NUMA system

Tags: c, linux, numa

I am trying to get my head around the `numa(3)` library on Linux.

I have a large array allocated (many GB of memory). Threads running on random NUMA nodes write to it, as such pages are faulted in on random NUMA memory nodes (default NUMA policy).

At the end of threaded calculation I have a single-threaded job to sum up the results. For that I first compress the array removing a lot of elements and then want to move the remainder to the NUMA node of the master thread.

The `move_pages` syscall is not the right one for the job because it requires an array entry for each page - too much overhead.

The documentation is unclear wether it is possible to force `numa_tonode_memory` to move faulted memory.

So the only way that I see is to use `mbind` with `MPOL_MF_MOVE`, but I can't get my head around creating a proper `nodemask` argument (or something else is failing). Here is as far as I got:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <numa.h>
#include <numaif.h>

int master_node;
nodemask_t master_nodemask;

// initializer
// has to be called from master/main thread
void numa_lock_master_thread() {
    int curcpu = sched_getcpu();
    if (curcpu >= 0) {
        // master_node = numa_node_of_cpu(curcpu);
        numa_run_on_node(master_node = numa_node_of_cpu(curcpu));
        if (master_node >= 0) {
            struct bitmask * bindmask = numa_bitmask_alloc(numa_num_possible_nodes());
            numa_bitmask_clearall(bindmask);
            numa_bitmask_setbit(bindmask, master_node);
            copy_bitmask_to_nodemask(bindmask, &master_nodemask);
            numa_bitmask_free(bindmask);
        }
    } else { // has never failed before
        perror("sched_getcpu");
    }
}

static inline void numa_migrate_pages_to_master_node(void * addr, unsigned long len) {
    if (master_node < 0)
        return;

    if ( mbind(   addr
                , len
                , MPOL_BIND
                , master_nodemask.n
                , numa_max_node()
                , MPOL_MF_MOVE)) {
        perror("mbind");
    }

}
```

from `/usr/include/numa.h`:

```
typedef struct {
        unsigned long n[NUMA_NUM_NODES/(sizeof(unsigned long)*8)];
} nodemask_t;
```

Sometimes I get `mbind: Bad address`, sometimes the call succeeds, but subsequent memory accesses give a `SIGSEGV`.

`addr` is always a valid pointer returned by

```
mmap(NULL, (num_pages) * sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE | (flags), -1, 0);
```

and `len` is page-aligned.

How can I make this work with as few syscalls as possible and without the large overhead that comes with `move_pages`?

And what is the proper way to set up the `nodemask` argument for `mbind`?

Comment: I see few problems with the code.  It looks like the parameter you are giving to `numa_migrate_pages_to_master_node()` might one source of the problem, but let's say that parameter is OK.  When using mbind(2), the fifth parameter is the number of (unsigned long)s you are supplying in the fourth parameter.  and that might not be equal to `numa_max_node()`, you can check that by comparing it to the exact size (`sizeof(n) / sizeof(*n)`).  But if you're using numa_*() functions you might probably want to use numa_set_membind() instead of mbind(2) itself.